# Как получить все связи между всеми таблицами в SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли способ получения связей между таблицами в SqlServer?

Я пробовал использовать `SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`, так как этот способ работал в MySQL, но в SQLServer `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` не имеет атрибутов `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` и `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`.

Comment: Например, `EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 А вообще в базе `sys` есть дофига интересных таблиц.

Comment: `select * from sys.foreign_keys`